# Generically setting accessibility identifier for automation tools?

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility, ios-ui-automation, ui-testing

We have a requirement in our project. We need to set accessibility identifier for all the components in approximately 40 view controllers. I was thinking how to achieve these basic work by getting each view controller name and iboutlet names in run time and generate ids by combining these values as accessibility id. For these, I need to get IBOutlet's names. How can I do that ? Or do you have any alternative idea for automating this process another way ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery)

It able to parse all your source files and provide you information about `IBOutlets` of all controllers:
You interested in `classes -> variables -> attributes`

You can generate inline for all such variables `didSet` block in which you will setup proper accessibility identifier

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link and you find a great solution to automate setting accessibilityIdentifier with the same name of the variable

https://medium.com/getpulse/https-medium-com-dinarajas-fixing-developer-inconveniences-ios-automation-e4832108051f

```
import UIKit

protocol AccessibilityIdentifierInjector {
    func injectAccessibilityIdentifiers()
}

extension AccessibilityIdentifierInjector {
    func injectAccessibilityIdentifiers() {
        var mirror: Mirror? = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        repeat {
            if let mirror = mirror {
                injectOn(mirror: mirror)
            }
            mirror = mirror?.superclassMirror
        } while (mirror != nil)
    }

    private func injectOn(mirror: Mirror) {
        for (name, value) in mirror.children {
            if var value = value as? UIView {
                UnsafeMutablePointer(&value)
                    .pointee
                    .accessibilityIdentifier = name
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController: AccessibilityIdentifierInjector {}
extension UIView: AccessibilityIdentifierInjector {}

class BaseView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        injectAccessibilityIdentifiers()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        injectAccessibilityIdentifiers()
    }
}
```

**How to use it**

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController {

    let asd1 = BaseView()
    let asd2 = BaseView()
    let asd3 = BaseView()
    let asd4 = BaseView()
    let asd5 = BaseView()
    let asd6 = BaseView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        [asd1, asd2, asd3, asd4, asd5, asd6].forEach {
            print($0.accessibilityIdentifier)
        }
    }


}
```